# ASP.NET MVC: jQuery UI Selectable Form Posting and Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, selectable

I have a list of items that I display to a user and allow them to select one or more of them by utilizing the jQuery UI Selectable interaction.  In order to post the selected values back to the Controller I am including a hidden input field within each selectable item that I am setting via javascript on the selected event. Here is an example of how I have it setup

Model

```
public class ItemsViewModel
{
     public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Html

```
<ul id="Items">
     <li>
          <label>Item 1</label>
          <input type="hidden" id="Items[0]_Id" name="Id" value="1" />
          <input type="hidden" id="Items[0]_Selected" name="Items[0].Selected" class="is-selected" value="False" />
     </li>
     <li>
          <label>Item 2</label>
          <input type="hidden" id="Items[1]_Id" name="Items[1].Id" value="2" />
          <input type="hidden" id="Items[1]_Selected" name="Items[1].Selected" class="is-selected" value="False" />
     </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
 $('#Items').selectable({
        filter: 'li',
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.selected).find('input.is-selected').val('True');
        },
        unselected: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.unselected).find('input.is-selected').val('False');
        }
    });
```

My first question, although this works, it isn't the prettiest solution.  Does anyone have any better ways of posting the selectable items?

Second, I need to ensure that the user has selected at least one item from the list.  Is it possible to hook up jQuery client side validation to ensure that the user has selected at least one item?  I do have some thoughts about ways to implement this and I have no problem creating a custom validation attribute but I thought I would ask if it has already been done or the best way to of doing it before I threw something together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Youu haven't shown the code you use to post the items.  That seems to be the interesting bit, to me.

As for relying on hidden fields, I don't know why you'd do that. Why not just populate an array of items in the selected event, then send that array when doing the AJAX POST?

```
itemsToPost = [];

$('#Items').selectable({ 
    filter: 'li', 
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        itemsToPost.push( {id: ui.attr('id'), name:ui.text()}); 
    }, 
    ...

$.ajax({url     : "/whatever/ASPNETMVC/Endpoint",
        cache   : false,
        type    : "POST", // http method
        dataType: "json",
        data    : itemsToPost,
        error   : function(xhr,status,error){
                ...
        },
        success : function(msg, arg2, xhr){
                ...
        });
```

Comment: I have definitely thought of this approach but I was hoping to get an approach that allows for jQuery client side validation on the selectable list using the .NET data annotation attributes.  And the reason there isn't any code for posting the items is that by using hidden fields, the asp.net framework automatically binds the fields to the model.  No code needed for posting.